# Posting a download to bitbucket from a shell script

Tags: shell, bitbucket

I'd like to be able to fully-automate the process of packaging the release of an application (in Xcode) via shell script and I'd like the zip archive that is released to be a download on bitbucket.  Is there a way to programmatically make a (zip) file available as a download on bitbucket?

Comment: Did you wrote a script for this in the meantime? I'm looking for one myself.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I got distracted from the particular project I'd been working on at the time and haven't cycled back to it yet.  If I were going to do it now, my first thought would be to write a script in Python using [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), but I'd still be concerned about the authentication issue.

Comment: I'm also interested in this. @MartinScharrer do you have a solution?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: No, I don't have a solution so far.

Comment: You can vote for the [feature request](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/4550/allow-uploading-of-file-for-downloads-via) on Bitbucket.

Comment: @Isaac ,please see my answer and accept that to help others landing on this page go directly to solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure you can do it with a shell script, or at least it'd be somewhat tough.  There is a bitbucket api (http://bitbucket.org/api/) but it looks read-only for the time being.

My suggestion is to use some kind of client-side http/url library in your favorite language to download the .../downloads page, grab all the `<input>`'s of the form, and repost an upload.  You'll want to look into posting `multipart/form-data` POST's.  Other than that, I'm not sure I can be of much help.

Comment: This is what I suspected--even just confirming my suspicion is helpful.  I'm fairly confident that I can use `curl` to put together the necessary GETs/POSTs, but I was really hoping to avoid this kind of screen-scraping-like upload, especially because of authentication issues.

Comment: @isaac yeah, you could try shell and curl, but it might just be easier to use `libcurl` or something... the scraping isn't perfect, but it's the best you can do I think :-/  You might consider posting on bitbuckets user mailing list

Answer (score 7):

I made one which I use to post nightly builds from my buildbot.
It's available for both *Bash* and *Batch*, works fine so far.

You can find it here, it's well commented and requires *cURL* and *grep*:
**https://bitbucket.org/Swyter/bitbucket-curl-upload-to-repo-downloads**

**Good:** Barebones, just 46 LOC, with CSRF handling.
**Bad:** Doesn't check for captcha or success, you can easily do that yourself parsing the page if you need it.

Comment: By far the easiest way I've found to do this from a bash script!

Answer (score 7):

They have provided API for this . Find it [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/downloads-resource-812221853.html#downloadsResource-POSTafile).

Comment: This is definitely what you want to use. As one commend:
`curl -u {username} -X POST https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username or teamname}/{repo_slug}/downloads -F files=@{filename}`